# scope in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have encountered the following curious piece of code:

```
function foo(){
    works = {hello:"world"};
    function bar(){
        alert('does not work');
    }
    var notwork = {hello:"world"};
}
foo();
alert(works.hello);
alert(notwork.hello);
```

Can someone please explain to me why works work, and notwork doesn't work? Or point me out to a good resource that explains this in detail.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**var notwork** creates a local variable valid only for the runtime of the function.

**works** creates a global variable that is valid throughout the javascript runtime.

Comment: No. Local variables are very much valid after function execution. That's the reason **Javascript has closures**.

Comment: As much as I agree, in this example the variable is NOT valid after function execution. Correct me if I am wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`var` declares a variable as "local" to the function it's defined in.

Without `var`, you `works` variable is global : it can be seen/accessed/used from anywhere.

With `var`, your `notwork` variable is local to the `foo` function : it cannot be seen/used from outside of that function.

For more informations, you can take a look at the documentation of the [`var` statement on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/var), which states *(quoting)* :

> The scope of a variable is the current
>   function or, for variables declared
>   outside a function, the current
>   application.
>
> Using `var` outside a function is
>   optional; assigning a value to an
>   undeclared variable implicitly
>   declares it as a global variable.
>   
> However, it is recommended to always
>   use `var`, and it is necessary within
>   functions in the following situations:
>
> - If a variable in a scope containing the function (including the global
>     scope) has the same name.
> - If recursive or multiple functions use variables with the same name and
>     intend those variables to be local.
>
> Failure to declare the variable in
>   these cases will very likely lead to
>   unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

You've missed out the `var` keyword so `works` is being defined on the global object.

You want

```
var works = ...
```